Definition of dimension of algebraic variety and its invariance on the open covering
My question is about one of definitions of the dimension of algebraic variety. I will provide some definitions, since in different literature the terminology varies.
Definition 1. A prevariety is a ringed space $(X, O_X)$ such that:

$X$ is irreducible;
$O_X$ is a sheaf of $K$-valued functions;
There exists an open cover $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of $X$, such that, for each $i$ we have that $(U_i, O_{X|U_i})$ is isomorphic to some affine variety over the field $K$.

Definition 2. Let $X$ be a prevariety. We say that $X$ is an algebraic variety if for any prevariety $Y$, and any pair of morphisms $f_1, f_2: Y \to X$, the set $\{P \in Y \mid f_1(P) = f_2(P)\}$ is a closed subset of $Y$.
Definition 3. If $X$ is an affine variety, define $\dim X$ to be the length of the longest chain of prime ideals $p_0 \subsetneq p_1 \subsetneq ... \subsetneq n$ of $K[X]$ (the Krull dimension of $K[X]$). For such a chain we say it has length $n$.
Definition 4. If $X$ is an algebraic variety and assume $X = \cup_{i \in I}U_i$, then define $\dim X = \sup_{i \in I}\{\dim U_i\}$.
Question: Suppose we are given a ringed space $(X, O_X)$, which is a variety, and we are given two different open covering $(U_i)_{i \in I}, (V_j)_{j \in J}$ which satisfy the condition in Definition 1. We naturally would like to have an invariant definition of the dimension of $X$. I am struggling to show that Definition 4 is indeed invariant of the chosen covering.
Attempt in reasoning: Let $d_U = \sup_{i \in I}\{\dim U_i\}$, $d_X = \sup_{j \in J}\{\dim V_j\}$ and suppose $d_U > d_V$. Then there exists $k \in I$, such that $\dim U_k > \dim V_j$, for all $j \in J$. Prime ideals in $K[U_k]$ correspond to affine subvarieties in $U_k$, so there exists a chain of subvarieties $S_0 \subsetneq ... \subsetneq S_{d_U}$ of irreducible closed subsets of $U_k$, and therefore of $X$. Since $d_U > d_V$, $S_{d_U} \nsubseteq V_j$, for all $j \in J$... And after this, I am unfortunately stuck. I don't know if this direction even brings the desired contradiction.
I would very much appreciate any help in clarifying, how to show that such a definition of dimension of a variety is well-defined, as well as any corrections to what I've written. Thank you.

I suggest introducing a choice-free definition of dimension, verify that it coincides with yours, and finally check how the dimension (with the new definition) can be obtained from an open covering.
Definition. Let $X$ be a topological space. We define its dimension to be the supremum of all $n \geq 0$ such that there exists a chain of closed (nonempty) irreducible subsets
$$Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset \dots \subset Z_n$$
of $X$ (here, "$\subset$" means strict inclusion).
Fact 1. Let $X$ be an affine variety. The dimension of $X$ is the supremum of all $n \geq 0$ such that there exists a chain of prime ideals
$$\mathfrak{p}_0 \subset \mathfrak{p}_1 \subset \dots \subset \mathfrak{p}_n$$
in $K[X]$.
Proof. It follows immediately from the correspondence between closed irreducible subsets of $X$ and prime ideals of $K[X]$.
Fact 2. Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{U}$ an open covering of $X$. Then the dimension of $X$ is the supremum of $\{\dim U \ | \ U \in \mathcal{U}\}$.
Proof. Let $U \in \mathcal{U}$, and let $Z'_0 \subset Z'_1 \subset \dots \subset Z'_n$ be a chain of closed irreducible subsets of $U$. Taking closures, we get a chain of closed irreducible subsets of $X$ with strict inclusions. Indeed, the closure of an irreducible subset is again irreducible, and the inclusions are still strict because the $Z'_i$ are closed in $U$.
Conversely, if $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset \dots \subset Z_n$ is a chain of closed irreducible subsets of $X$, then there exists $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $Z_0 \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Intersecting the chain with $U$, we get a chain of closed irreducible subsets in $U$ with strict inclusions. Indeed, nonempty open subsets of irreducible spaces are again irreducible, and the inclusions are strict because nonempty open subsets are dense in an irreducible topological space.
